# Using Google Map in Xamarin

Tags: android, google-maps, xamarin.android, xamarin

I am trying to use Google Map API in Xamarin for Android and so far its been a hair pulling experience. I am new to Xamarin and trying to get the hang of it. I have tested some basic controls and they seem to work fine.Now I am trying to use Google Map Api. I have inserted the Api key in AndroidManifest.xml as per the Xamarin documentation. I have the following code in my Main.axml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Here is my activity class

```
[Activity (Label = "Testing", MainLauncher = true)]
    public class MainActivity : Android.GoogleMaps.MapActivity
    {

        protected override bool IsRouteDisplayed {
            get {
                return false;
            }
        }

        protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate (bundle);


            SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main);

            // Get our button from the layout resource,
            // and attach an event to it
            //Button button = FindViewById<Button> (Resource.Id.myButton);

            //button.Click += delegate {
            //    button.Text = string.Format ("{0} clicks!", count++);
            //};
        }
    }
```

When I run the above code it throws an exception

```
Android.Views.InflateException: Loading
```

I don't get any details of the error like we normally do in VS. I have no idea what is wrong I'm just following the documentation blindly at the moment to see something on the screen and then play with it but that's not happening any soon I guess!

I am targeting Google API Version 8 for this test project.

Kindly suggest what am I missing here?

Comment: How about OpenStreetMap support? If you are not strictly bound to google maps, I can post quite a sample that uses OpenStreetMap.

Comment: @HuseyinUslu My only requirement is that I have to show nearest gas stations and then draw a path to any gas station that the user selects. If OpenStreetMap supports those features I'll be glad for your help. Thanks Mate!

Comment: Check ur integration steps and api key. this might be helpfull http://appliedcodelog.blogspot.in/2015/04/build-google-map-v2-in-xamarin-android.html

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Google Maps V2, take a look at this page:
http://components.xamarin.com/view/googleplayservices/

And if you are targeting API 8, don't forget to reference the Mono.Android.Support.v4 assemly, and use the elements accordingly!

Here is how my Layout looks like:

```
<FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/mapView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:longClickable="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textLayout"
        android:layout_above="@+id/footerLayout" />
```

And my class:

```
public class GoogleMapActivity : Android.Support.V4.App.FragmentActivity
{
      protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
      {
        var fragTx = SupportFragmentManager.BeginTransaction();
        var mapFragment = Android.Gms.Maps.SupportMapFragment.NewInstance(mapOptions);
        fragTx.Add(Resource.Id.mapView, mapFragment, "mapView");
        fragTx.Commit();
      }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks Roosevelt, I have tried your code but it seems that I am missing something. I am using VS and I have already added reference of Mono.Android.Support.v4 assembly. However when I am trying to build your code it is giving me this error.

Error 5  package com.google.android.maps does not exist
 private native void n_onFocusChanged (com.google.android.maps.ItemizedOverlay p0, com.google.android.maps.OverlayItem p1);
 C:\src\mono\com\google\android\maps\ItemizedOverlay_OnFocusChangeListenerImplementor.java

Comment: Seems like I need to add some package but not sure which one, from where and how?

Comment: Have you tried this solution? http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/1018/problem-with-google-maps

Comment: I have seen that and some other threads but they are getting error when they try to run the code on emulator. In my case I get the error when I am building the solution so there is no way to find out what I am missing.

Comment: You are running in emulator? I don't recommend using an emulator it's so slow... Btw. have you created the emulator with Google API? Have you tried on actual device?

Comment: No I haven't tested it on real device yet. I have create emulator with Google Api yes. My question is that if it is not compiling how can it be an emulator issue?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't exactly answer for your question but an alternative;

I've been using OpenStreetMaps with [leaflet](http://leafletjs.com/) and/or [mapbox](http://www.mapbox.com/) using xamarin over android. Though I'm not sure if you can filter out gas stations or so.

Here is the code piece I'm using to render mobile maps;

```
public class MainActivity : Activity//, ILocationListener
{
    private WebView _webView;
    private MonkeyWebViewClient _webViewClient;
    private MonkeyWebChromeClient _webChromeClient;

    ...

    protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
    {
        Log.Verbose (LogAppTag, "Init webview..");
        _webView = FindViewById<WebView> (Resource.Id.webView1);
        _webView.Settings.JavaScriptEnabled = true;

        _webViewClient = new MonkeyWebViewClient (this);
        _webChromeClient = new MonkeyWebChromeClient ();
        _webViewClient.OnLoadComplete += WebLoadComplete;

        _webView.SetWebViewClient(_webViewClient);
        _webView.SetWebChromeClient(_webChromeClient);      

        _webView.LoadUrl("file:///android_asset/Content/Map/Map.html");

    ...

    void WebLoadComplete (object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Log.Verbose(Logging.AppTag, "WebLoadComplete()");
        _webView.LoadUrl("javascript:SetLocation(" + _location.Latitude + "," + _location.Longitude + ");");    
    }
    ...
    class MonkeyWebChromeClient : WebChromeClient {
        public override bool OnJsAlert(WebView view, string url, string message, JsResult result)
        {
            // the built-in alert is pretty ugly, you could do something different here if you wanted to
            return base.OnJsAlert(view, url, message, result);
        }
    }

    class MonkeyWebViewClient : WebViewClient 
    {
        public bool LoadingFinished { get; private set; }

        public delegate void LoadCompleteHandler(object sender, EventArgs e);
        public event LoadCompleteHandler OnLoadComplete;

        Activity context;

        public MonkeyWebViewClient(Activity context)
        {
            this.context = context;
        }
        public override bool ShouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, string url)
        {
            view.LoadUrl (url);
            return true;
        }

        public override void OnPageStarted (WebView view, string url, Android.Graphics.Bitmap favicon)
        {
            this.LoadingFinished = false;
            base.OnPageStarted (view, url, favicon);
        }

        public override void OnPageFinished (WebView view, string url)
        {
            this.LoadingFinished = true;

            var handler = OnLoadComplete;
            if (handler != null) handler(this, EventArgs.Empty);

            base.OnPageFinished (view, url);
        }
    }
```

And here is the html code we load in webview;

```
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />   
<!-- mapbox -->
<script src='http://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/v1.3.1/mapbox.js'></script>
<link href='http://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/v1.3.1/mapbox.css' rel='stylesheet' />    
<!-- mapbox -->
    </head>
<style>
    body {
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
    }
    html, body, #map {
        height: 100%;
    }
</style>
<div id="map"></div>        
<script src="JS/Map.js"></script>           
 </html>
```

And the JS code that can communicate with C# code; you probably want to create a new map over mapbox and change raistlinthewiz.map-oukwofv3 part.

```
    // map code.            
function SetLocation(lat, lng)
{
    var latlng = new L.LatLng(parseFloat(lat), parseFloat(lng));

    // mapbox
    var map = L.mapbox.map('map', 'raistlinthewiz.map-oukwofv3').setView(latlng, 18);                   

    L.mapbox.markerLayer({ // this feature is in the GeoJSON format: see geojson.org for the full specification
        type: 'Feature',
        geometry: {
            type: 'Point', // coordinates here are in longitude, latitude order because x, y is the standard for GeoJSON and many formats
            coordinates: [parseFloat(lng), parseFloat(lat)]
        },
        properties: { // one can customize markers by adding simplestyle properties http://mapbox.com/developers/simplestyle/
            title: 'A Single Marker',
            description: 'Just one of me',              
            'marker-size': 'large'
        }
    }).addTo(map);
}
```

If you also need, I can provide a sample that uses vanilla-leaflet.